# Ruby on Rails routes: resources on collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I need a link, which would point to all jobs, tagged as PHP. This structure makes sense to me:

> site.com/jobs/skills/php

How do I do this in Rails?

```
  resources :jobs do
    collection do
      resources :skills, as: :find_by_skill
    end
  end
```

However, this does not work, when I try to call the jobs_find_by_skill(skill) helper. Where is a problem? If this cannot be done, could you suggest a better URL structure for this kind of purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mix up *tags* and *skills* here. I'm using *tags* for this answer.

The most common way would to make your url working would be nested resources

```
resources :jobs do
  resources :tags
end
```

Remember not to put subsequent resources in collection or member blocks. Then have a tags_controller.rb like this for example

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @jobs = Tag.find_by_name(params[:id]).jobs
  end
end
```

The corresponding association of *Job* and *Tag* needs to be there as well.

Hope that get you further.